# Pandas Python conditional

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = [{'Number':'0001',  'Name':'A','Course':'Eng','Score':81 },{'Number':'0001',  'Name':'A','Course':'Geo','Score':75},
       {'Number':'0002',  'Name':'B','Course':'Eng','Score': 76} , {'Number':'0002',  'Name':'B','Course':'Geo','Score':90 },
    {'Number':'0003',  'Name':'C','Course':'Eng','Score':81 },{'Number':'0003',  'Name':'C','Course':'Geo','Score':100, },
     {'Number':'0003',  'Name':'C','Course':'Bio','Score':90 }]


data = pd.DataFrame(d, index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
data

Course  Name    Number  Score
1   Eng A   0001    81
2   Geo A   0001    75
3   Eng B   0002    76
4   Geo B   0002    90
5   Eng C   0003    81
6   Geo C   0003    100
7   Bio C   0003    90
```

what I want is return only name C because C is the only one who score over 80 on every subject

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A groupby is what you want

```
grouped = data.groupby('Name').min()
print(grouped.loc[grouped['Score']>80].index[0])
```

This will give you

```
Out[1]: ['C']
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `filter` after `groupby` such as:

```
print (data.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: (x['Score'].min()>80)))
```

and you get

```
  Course Name Number  Score
5    Eng    C   0003     81
6    Geo    C   0003    100
7    Bio    C   0003     90
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `transform` with `all`

```
data.loc[data.Score.gt(80).groupby(data['Name']).transform('all'),'Name'].unique()
Out[9]: array(['C'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` with `unique`

```
data.loc[data.groupby('Name')['Score'].transform('min')>80].Name.unique()
```

Output:

```
array(['C'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way may be as following:

```
f = lambda group: group.name if all(group>80) else None
r = data.groupby(['Name'])['Score'].apply(f).dropna().values
print(r)

# Result: ['C']
```